# How to generate a staticmethod from a metaclass?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, static-methods

I'm trying to make a staticmethod, object-creation factory method for a bunch of classes via meta programming. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class PlayMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        newclass = super(PlayMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

        @staticmethod
        def make():
            print('meta make')

        setattr(newclass, make.__name__, make)

        return newclass

class Fritz(PlayMeta):
    pass

Fritz.make()
```

but when I run it I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Fritz' has no attribute 'make'
```

How do you do this? I have messages with a lot of fields and I want this to be a class that will create and generate different of these messages. This question is about the factory / creation part. I'm using Python 3.5. Thanks!

edit: 2nd, working version:

```
class PlayMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        newclass = super(PlayMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

        def instance_method(self, x, y, z):
            print('instance method', x, y, z)
        setattr(newclass, instance_method.__name__, instance_method)

        def static_make(x, y, z):
            print('static make', x, y, z)
        setattr(newclass, static_make.__name__, static_make)

        return newclass

class Fritz(metaclass=PlayMeta):
    pass

Fritz.static_make('a', [], 3)

f = Fritz()
f.instance_method('a', [], 3)
```

Successfully prints:

```
static make a [] 3
instance method a [] 3
```

How does Python distinguish an instance method from a class / static method, when they're defined and attached the same way? The presence of the word 'self'? Because that would be convenient, but a bit hokey.

edit2: Ah, it's probably **just in how it's called** - call it with an instance, and all is well with an instance-expecting method. But you could call either method, with or without an instance, and they would behave correctly or not, accordingly.

edit3, final form :) :

```
@staticmethod
def static_make(x, y, z):
    print('static make', x, y, z)
    setattr(newclass, 'static_make', static_make)
```

I don't know what (at)staticmethod adds -- version 2, above, worked -- but this is more self-documenting at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I entirely understand your plan. But assuming that `Fritz` is **not** supposed to be a metaclass itself but rather a regular class, you need to construct it like:

```
class Fritz(metaclass=PlayMeta):
    pass
```

As for the difference between static and instance methods, all regular functions behave like instance methods and if called on the instance will get it as the first positional argument (regardless of how it is named). You can try in your *2nd example* to call `f.static_method` or `Fritz.instance_method`, they behave identically. To find out more have a look at [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

The `staticmethod` decorator converts the regular function to a proper static method that will work the same way even when called on the instance (i.e. it won't get the instance as the first argument). But note that when applied the resulting object doesn't have the `__name__` attribute which you will need if you will generate these methods programmatically.

Also, the `dct` argument to `__new__` is the set of names and values that will be used to set the attributes of the new class, so it might be a good place to put the methods you create in your metaclass. This will also enable you to decide whether you want the `Fritz` class to be able to override the attributes from the metaclass or vice versa.

Example (with metaclass overriding the methods if they happen to be also defined on the class):

```
class PlayMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):

        def instance_method(self, x, y, z):
            print('instance method', x, y, z)

        def static_make(x, y, z):
            print('static make', x, y, z)

        return super(PlayMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, {**dct,
            instance_method.__name__: instance_method,
            static_make.__name__: staticmethod(static_make),
        })


class Fritz(metaclass=PlayMeta):
    ...


f = Fritz()
```

...

```
In [2]: f.instance_method(1, 2, 3)
instance method 1 2 3

In [3]: f.static_make(1, 2, 3)
static make 1 2 3

In [4]: Fritz.static_make(1, 2, 3)
static make 1 2 3

In [5]: Fritz.instance_method(1, 2, 3, 4)
instance method 2 3 4
```

Comment: Sorry man, apparently I have enough karma to edit other people's answers, and edited your answer instead of my own. I don't know how to undo it. I will, later, if I can. Your answer worked, and I've now edited my own, as I originally intended. Thanks very much!

Comment: The `staticmethod` decorator should be there; adding `make` like this does not automatically make it behave like a staticmethod.

Comment: @user2357112 I can only say what works and what doesn't. My first attempt at an (at)staticmethod failed. When I use the later, Fritz(metaclass=PlayMeta) version and put an (at)staticmethod decorator on static_make, Python unsurprisingly finds the decorator, not 'static_make', and fails to add it ("AttributeError: staticmethod' object has no attribute 'under-under-name-under-under'")

Comment: @JDonner: Yeah, that's just because you were trying to access `__name__` on a `staticmethod`. You need to either hardcode `"make"` (or `"static_make"` or whatever name you pick) or get the `__name__` from the underlying function at that point. Once you actually put the staticmethod on the class, accessing it will perform normal staticmethod descriptor access.

Comment: @user2357112 - wonderful. The line in question is now (barring typos): setattr(newclass, 'static_make', static_make). Thanks so much!

Comment: I was a bit hasty in my original answer, edited with proper use of `staticmethod`

Comment: @0101: I regret that I can only give you one point :). I'm surprised this isn't more carefully laid out in the docs, or else that there aren't more blogposts about it (getting more Google-juice) - you'd think that parsing and generating messages would be a common problem, and metaclasses, a common solution. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: The new revision is much better.